# Parsing the 'q' in drupal to get the current URL

Tags: theming

So I am attempting to parse out the URL, so that I can get a specific page template to be used for a specific URL; if the URL is example.com/team, then use page-team.tpl.php.

However, when I do this, the URL I am getting (via $_GET['q']) always seems to be the URL from where I was, not the one where I am currently at. If I directly navigate to example.com/team/surf, it gives me "team/surf"; if I go to example.com/team it gives
"team/surf." If I refresh the page, it will then give me the desired one.

I dropped this code into my template.php file.

```
function theme_preprocess(&$vars, $hook) {
  switch ($hook) {
    case 'page':   
      $normal_path = trim($_GET['q'], '/');
      $path_alias = drupal_get_path_alias($normal_path);
      $alias_parts = explode('/', $path_alias);

      if (($alias_parts[0] === 'team') && (count($alias_parts)) == 1) {
       $vars['template_file'] = 'page-team';
      }
      break;
    }
```

Do you have any idea on what is going on here?

Comment: Consider posting your solution as an answer and marking it as accepted so that others can easily find a solution

Comment: yup. didn't realize that. i'll have to update the answer in 4hrs.

Comment: It seems a localized situation; `$_GET['q']` is normally updated with the current value get from the page request. I have never seen that value being not correct. There could be code that alters that value, but from what being reported is not possible to know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why your code happens to fail in some cases, and in some cases not. But what I would try is replacing that code with the provided by Drupal [arg](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function.

On "team/surf", arg(0) will return "team", and arg(1) "surf". This is what I use myself, and hopefully that will solve the problem for you.

Comment: interestingly it came down to `dsm()`. So i wanted to check some variables before i moved forward. i was simply dumping them into `dsm()` just to see what my results were looking like. at the time, just seemed like a good idea. so `dsm($_GET['q'])` would output the previous url and not the current url. when i did a `print $_GET['q']` it would show me the current url as expected. 

as for arg(). good call on that one. i have seriously forgotten all about that one. thanks for the help.

Comment: @austin That is what happens sometimes with `dsm()`.

Comment: `THEME_preprocess_page()` is called after the messages HTML has been produced. So, when `drupal_set_message()` or anything that ends calling it is called from `THEME_preprocess_page()`, the message will only be displayed on the next page request. It explain why `dsm($_GET['q'])` prints the previous URL. Also, note the `dpm()` should be used instead of `dsm()`.

Comment: @Letharion - Pure `arg()` doesn't work with aliases. You have to add `drupal_get_path_alias()` as an argument of `arg()` like so: `arg(1, drupal_get_path_alias())`. Otherwise `arg(1)` will always return the node id.

Answer (score 2):

[There is no need to parse the `$_GET['q']` yourself.](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7)